# Replace all files of my Magento acidentally, how configure whit older Database manually

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I accidentally replaced all files from my Magento installation of my WebHost with files from a new installation. I need to replace it with the an older Database, that contains products and other information. 
I don't know how to do this manually. I'm new to Magento and have checked the etc/local directories but this contains correct information.
My question is... where do I have to modify the Magento installation to make it work with my older database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this some year ago. 
I had to reinstall clean Magento install, do the whole process, then import my old database.

It worked fine.
Hope it'll work for you